# AWS Mobile HUD AWS SNS pushManagerDidRegister but endpoint not created

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using AWS Mobile HUD with AWS SNS and am running into problems.

What works / was done already

- sucessfully created p12 universal certificate
- resources on AWS SNS created sucessfully by Mobile HUD
- topic created sucessfully by Mobile HUD
- integrated code into project
- integrated plist

the following code should register the app (device) with AWS SNS:

```
pushManager = AWSPushManager(forKey: ServiceKey)
pushManager?.delegate = self
pushManager?.registerForPushNotifications()
```

and - greatly enough `func pushManagerDidRegister(_ pushManager: AWSPushManager)` is called, indicating success. My `func pushManagerDidRegister(_ pushManager: AWSPushManager)` looks as fo

```
func pushManagerDidRegister(_ pushManager: AWSPushManager) {
    print("Successfully enabled Push Notifications on platform: \(pushManager.platformARN)")
    // Subscribe the first topic among the configured topics (all-device topic)
    if let defaultSubscribeTopic = pushManager.topicARNs?.first {
        let topic = pushManager.topic(forTopicARN: defaultSubscribeTopic)
        topic.subscribe()
    }
}
```

log output:

```
Successfully enabled Push Notifications on platform: Optional("arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:00000000:app/APNS/appname_MOBILEHUD_12345678")
```

but: **on AWS SNS resource no endpoint is created in this application / platformARN**

Interesting facts (maybe the reason)

- Build config is DEBUG
- Logged platformARN is RELEASE and not DEBUG

`edit`: After playing around with different swift compiler flags I managed to set the environment correclty. Now i get logging that the registration was successfull on the Sandbox Environment. But: **still no endpoint created on AWS SNS**.

any ideas on how i could proceed? I tried for 2 days now including recertification, rebuilding AWS, endless logging ;)

Comment: I am not familiar with what you are trying to do, just trying to help. But after reading the documentation about AWS SNS, it mentions about a device token that needs to be send to AWS SNS to have it registered as an endpoint. I don't see that in the code you provided.

Comment: @JackG. thank you for the interest in my troubles - it should be handled by the call of `registerForPushNotifications`  (3rd line in my code). This is a framework function by AWS SNS which should do everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: [AWS push notification service integration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064686/aws-push-notification-service-integration-error)

The issue was with missing privileges on AWS Mobile HUB. Sadly no sensible error was created ;)

Adding the policy AmazonSNSFullAccess solved it.

Answer (score 3):

so I looked for the issue in docs and their github. 
What I noticed that they are using `AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput` which you don't have, also you have to get device token from `func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)` and register it.

anyway it should be something like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

let deviceTokenString = "\(deviceToken)".stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"<>"))
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
print("deviceTokenString: \(deviceTokenString)")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceTokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
mainViewController()?.displayDeviceInfo()

let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
request.token = deviceTokenString
request.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), block: { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if task.error != nil {
        print("Error: \(task.error)")
    } else {
        let createEndpointResponse = task.result as! AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
        print("endpointArn: \(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn)")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn, forKey: "endpointArn")
        self.mainViewController()?.displayDeviceInfo()
    }

    return nil
})
}
```

please, update me what happened
and good luck

Comment: This is the approach if using vanilla SNS, but i am using AWS MObileHUB which should handle this part on it's own :/

Comment: I am apologizing for this mistake.